# How to return unique values on criteria basis but rows concatenated and separated by comma in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm tryng to get this to work, but I keep getting the error:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ";FALSE;IF(A22:A32=A2:A10;K22:K32;"")))`
`Array arguments to EQ are of different size`

Here is the file with the data, attempt and the expected result:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(A2:A19;lambda(Σ;join(", ";unique(filter(K22:K;A22:A=Σ)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This lalso helped me assimilate `lambda` a bit more. Thanks!